# How to print numpy array in columns without using pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Here is my basic code:

```
import numpy as np
a = numpy.asarray([ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ])
```

I want to print the arrays as follows:

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

Also, how would I approach the same concept if my a array has 1000 embedded list in it?

Comment: Have you tried writing one or two loops?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Trying to think how to do two loops. Any hints?

Comment: For each column: print each column separated by line breaks; For each row in every column: print each value separated by spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a powerful one-line solution without loops:

```py
print('\n'.join(map(lambda line: ' '.join(map(str, line)), a.T)))
```

`a.T` transpose the 2D array, the first `map` encode a line in a string and the second one concatenate the string lines (by using `\n` between).

This is an alternative version with generators (likely slower):

```py
print('\n'.join(' '.join(str(item) for item in line) for line in a.T))
```

Yet another solution with one loop (likely even slower):

```py
for line in a.T:
    print(' '.join(str(item) for item in line))
```

Note the last version produce a trailing new line.

Comment: Richard can you show how to do it in a loop as well please?

Comment: @user8607309 I edited the question to include that.

Answer (score 0):

You could also make use of `str`:

```
print(str(a.T).translate(str.maketrans({'[':'',']':''})))
1 4 7
 2 5 8
 3 6 9

print(str(a.T).replace('[', '').replace(']',''))
1 4 7
 2 5 8
 3 6 9
print(str(a.T).translate(str.maketrans({'[':'',']':''})).replace('\n ', '\n'))
 1 4 7
 2 5 8
 3 6 9
```